# Password required to suspend in Kubuntu after the latest upgrade

Tags: kubuntu, kde, pam, kde5

Looks like something broke PAM yet again. Kubuntu with the Backports PPA asks for my password instead of suspending after a period of inactivity. Anyone found the reason and/or a workaround yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed now. Maybe these were some cache issues.